# Log axis scale not formatting data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a log-normal plot with an array of data, but when I apply a log scale to the y axis, it only scales the axis ticks and not the actual data being plotted.  In summary, all the data is plotted linearly, but the axis scale is shown as log.  Below is my axis code:

```
var y = d3.scale.log()
  .domain([.001,maxData])
  .range([graphHeight, 0]);            

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("right")
  .ticks(20, ".2")
  .tickSize(-graphWidth,0,0);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "yaxis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" +graphWidth + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text") 
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 70)
  .attr("x", -graphHeight/2)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("YLabel");


var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d,i) { 
return (i-0.5)*horizontalBarDistance; 
    })
.y(function(d) { 
    return graphHeight - d*100; 
    })


for (names in dataArrays)
 {
  svg.append("svg:path").attr("class","line").attr("d", line(dataArrays[names]));          
 }
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using the log scale anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the scale in your code for it to make a difference. At the moment, your code contains no reference to it apart from when you're assigning it to the axis. You probably want something like

```
.y(function(d) { 
  return y(d); 
})
```

in the definition of your line generator.